# Validate user's input from dictionary

Tags: python, validation, input

I am trying to validate the user's input for 2 options (one is an int and one is a word). I have attempted to use the try and except values however, they appear to just break the program. Basically I just need the user to only be able to enter in S,D or Q for the human's turn and 1,2 or 3 for the comp strategy.

the 2 types of validation are

```py
human_input_map = {
    's': 'Steal',
    'd': 'Deal',
    'q': 'Quit'
}

#Human's turn
human = input('Steal, Deal or Quit [s|d|q]?: ')              
human = human_input_map[human]
```

AND

```
print('1. Always Steal')
print('2. Always Deal')
print('3. Random\n')

comp_strat = int(input('Which strategy for the computer [1,2,3]? '))
print(" ")
    
    sd = ["Steal", "Deal"]
    if comp_strat == int(1):
        comp_choice = 'Steal'
    elif comp_strat == int(2):
        comp_choice = 'Deal'
    elif comp_strat == int(3):
        comp_choice = random.choice(sd)
```

As always I thank you for your wisdom!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do simply check if the user's input is a key from your pre-defined dictionary!

```py
human_input_map = {
    's': 'Steal',
    'd': 'Deal',
    'q': 'Quit'
}

#Human's turn
human = input('Steal, Deal or Quit [s|d|q]?: ').lower()
if human not in human_input_map:
    # add your logic here
    print("Your input is not valid!")
else:
   human = human_input_map[human]
```

You can use the same approach for the other input too!